# iPhone Keyboard | Search

Tags: html

I have a search field I am wanting to ensure the "GO" button appears for the iPhone keyboard and once the user has inputed their search or tap out of the input for the keyboard to disappear.

Searched through stackoverflow and some suggestions were to change the input type to "search". This did nothing but change the appearance of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer to this was to rip Googles search!

The following code does EXACTLY as I'm wanting above which adds the "Go" button to the keyboard and retracts the keyboard once pressed.

```
<form action="/search">
   <input type="text" placeholder"Search" />
</form>
```